# Typecasting in Firebase Realtime database security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We have a database we store UIDs as numbers inside a nested structure.

I've been trying to setup conditional access to certain nodes, and wanted to know if there is any way to typecast inside rules.

Here's an example to explain the problem:

```
".read": "data.child('members/0').val() == auth.uid && auth.uid!=null",
```

In our DB, under `members/0` we have user UIDs stored as numbers, whereas `auth.uid` seems to return a string.

This condition always fails due to this (At least what I think is happening).

What would be the best way to go about resolving this issue without having to tinker with the database itself?

**EDIT**

Problem:
I'm trying to read a database value stored as a `Number` and compare it to `auth.uid`, which is a `String` in Firebase database security rules. Wanted to know if there is any way of comparing these two values

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having, not what typecasting means here. Can you edit your question to show a read operation that you think should work, but that is being rejected by this rule?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen simplified the problem, I hope this makes it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDs in Firebase are by definition strings, so even if your underlying auth system uses numeric IDs they will be stored as strings in Firebase. I *highly* recommend storing the UIDs in Firebase as strings too for that reason.

That said, you can coerce the number to a string in your current rule and then compare it to the UID string:

```
".read": " ''+data.child('members/0').val() == auth.uid && auth.uid!=null "
//
```